# How to create Vertx Webclient running on WorkerVerticle instead main verticle?

Tags: vert.x

I would like to create WebClient working on WorkerVerticle, not on my main verticle, is it possible? I only see Vertx and VertxOptions when trying to create WebClient. I do not see the option to choose on which verticle this Webclient should run.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use worker verticles - executeBlocking is the preferred alternative

Second, the client will be created on the verticle you create it on - so deploy a worker verticle and then create the webclient in that verticle

Comment: I was able to reconstruct my code to be not blocking (but I would not tell that it was very simple). 
If I have a webclient used in Verticle1 and I want to use another webclient in Verticle2 - I should just create it - from the same Vertx object probably? And then webClient1 and webClient2 will be working separately and will not be problem for each other?

deployFirstVerticleWithWebClient(); // create the first webclient here, under Verticle1
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions); // then create second webclient, under verticle2

Comment: yes - each verticle can create its own webclient and use them independently

Comment: it is very helpful, thanks. Where can I learn such things? I tried to get information about that in Vertx documentation but it was hard to find. How did you learned about this, what source?

Comment: You can get my course on udemy to learn more -> https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/learn/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C

And can always reach out for 1 on 1 sessions https://consulting.aawadia.dev/

Comment: Ok, I bought it and I am learning from the crucial chapters of your course about event loop and multithreading, I hope this helps.
If I create a second WebClient on the Verticle - how will it behave? (possibly it is not the best idea, it is I think better to create this new Verticle)